# How to serialize YamlNode to string

Tags: kotlin

I use kaml to parse yaml file.

After Yaml tree manipulation, I want to serialize the tree back to the file.

So far, it looks like I have to iterate over the tree and construct yaml file line by line.

Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

So I got a reply from the library author and Kaml is not intended for general-purpose usage.

The suggestion is to try SnakeYaml.